# how to build flutter apk in c partition of windows10

Tags: flutter, dart, apk, release

I have one partition c in my pc
my project track `C:\Users\Eng.Ahmed\AndroidStudioProjects\project_name`
my flutter path is `C:\Users\Eng.Ahmed\Downloads\flutter`
I was working on linux before and I couldn't build the apk or export the path

```
export PATH=C:\Users\Eng.Ahmed\Downloads\flutter/bin:$PATH
```

I get this

```
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

when I type  flutter build apk in terminal I get

```
'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

how to solve the problem?

Comment: "export" is linux-specific syntax for setting environment variables. Use the Windows equivalent when using Windows command lines.

Comment: [Flutter docs for updating path](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path)